# Passing degree symbol ( ° ) from XML to java

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding

I am working on a java application where I am making request using Fiddler by passing input in XML format. Some of my input values have (°) symbol for example °K. My java application is using ZMQ to receive request. Once i receive request I am converting it into String as follows:

```
ZFrame request = getFrame(2, receivedRequest);
String inputString = new String(request.getData());
```

When I do this `inputString` contains `?K` instead of `°K`. I also tried following code:

```
ZFrame request = getFrame(2, receivedRequest);
String inputString = new String(request.getData(),Charset.availableCharsets().get("UTF-8"));
```

but this also giving me `?K`. While passing XML from fiddler I included `encoding='UTF-8'`. Please help.

Comment: How do you know that the String contains ?K rather than °K ? Maybe it's the media you're printing your String to, that doesn't support ° or at least not without encoding configuration.

Comment: @kumesana Based on this string(°K) I have to perform some task but I am unable to do, rest all are working fine as i don't have this symbol(°). Also by printing and by debugging i came to know that it's having '?' instead of '°'

Comment: As I said, it may be the printing that displays ? rather than ° and not the String itself being corrupted. Though that's much less likely in debugging. With your second version, though, the String cannot be wrongly built if the bytes given by request.getData() are correct. I suggest you write these bytes in a file as-is, in binary not text, and then check that the content is correct. You will find that it is not.

Comment: @kumesana I tried and its writing '?K' in file also.

Comment: Okay so you knew that so far. I'm afraid I have no idea how you can obtain ZFrames through Fiddler.